# Trouble understanding tensor notation for relativistic transformations

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

For $x^\mu$ with $\mu_0=t, \mu_i = x^i$ and $\eta_{\mu v}$ the metric tensor with diagonal (-1,1,1,1) and zeros elsewhere, the condition for equivalence of inertial frames is stated as for some "coordinate transformation" $x \to x'$, (1) $\eta_{\mu v} dx'^\mu dx'^v = \eta_{\mu v}dx^\mu dx^v$ or equivalently (2) $\eta_{\mu v} \frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\rho}\frac{\partial x'^v}{\partial x^\sigma} = \eta_{\rho\sigma} $.

I can understand (1) as saying that the lorentzian metric/spacetime interval is preserved. I don't understand how (2) says the same thing or what's going on there mathematically. It can't be partial derivatives of a function taking $x$ to $x'$ since then the equality obviously wouldn't hold in general, but then I'm not sure what they are partial derivatives of, if anything. Any clarification is appreciated

Comment: Only Lorentz transformations preserve the Minkowski metric. So the mappings $x\to x’$ are very specific functions, not arbitrary functions.

Comment: It’s not correct to write $\mu_0=t$. You can write $x^0=t$, or $x^\mu=(t,x,y,z)$.